# how to consume the latest text file data send in kafka and write back in another text file using c#?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I have sent one text file of data to Kafka producer after reading that file in string. Now I want to consume the same data in text file. How do I consume it?

```
var fileName = @"D:\kafka_examples\new2.txt";
var options = new KafkaOptions(new Uri("http://localhost:9092"),
              new Uri("http://localhost:9092"));
var router = new BrokerRouter(options);
var consumer = new KafkaNet.Consumer(new ConsumerOptions("Hello-Kafka",
               new BrokerRouter(options)));
var text="";
//Consume returns a blocking IEnumerable (ie: never ending stream)
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
  File.Delete(fileName);
}

foreach (var message in consumer.Consume())
{
  Console.WriteLine("Response: P{0},O{1} : {2}",
                   message.Meta.PartitionId, message.Meta.Offset,
                  text= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Value));
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName))
  {
    sw.WriteLine(text);
  }
}
```

I tried this but the file is not written  in given text file. All messages are coming. I  want only the last message.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of the "latest" message in a stream; they are infinite.

But what you could do is try to lookup the current latest offset when your code starts, then subtract one (or the number of lines in the file), then `seek` the consumer group there and `break` the `for` loop on reading just those many  messages.

i.e.

```
var filename = ...
var lines = linesInFile(filename)
var consumer = ... // (with a consumer group id)
var latestOffset = seekToEnd(consumer, -1 * lines) // second param is the delta offset from the end

var i = lines;
foreach (var message in consumer.Consume()) {
   ... 

   if (i <= 0) break;
}
```

Also, Kafka is not an http service. Remove `http://` and your duplicate localhost address from the code